# Navigate to page based on itemview clicked item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

i have a simple list that is bound to a gridview control, upon the itemview's click event i'd like to navigate to the page.

My class looks like;

```
public class GetMenu
    {
        public string titleName { get; set; }
        public string imagePath { get; set; }
        public string pagePath { get; set; }
    }
```

An example of the data with the list;

```
new GetMenu(){titleName = "Services", imagePath = "Bouquets.xaml", pagePath="Services.xaml"}
```

For the click even have the following;

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

I believe i need to extract the click event data from e, i'm a little unsure on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, i.e you want to get 'clicked' item, then it should be fairly easy:

```
var getMenu = (GetMenu)e.ClickedItem;
```

Now you have the item and you can use the properties inside as navigation parameters.

Is that what you had in mind?

[EDIT]

The navigation itself is fairly simple, too. If you're in code-behind, you have to:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourViewForTheItem), parameters);
```

e.g.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailsView), getMenu);
```

`parameters` is an `object`, so you will have to cast it appropriately in `OnNavigatedTo` in the target view.

If you're using any kind of MVVM framework, there are services for that too, e.g. Caliburn.Micro has `INavigationService`.

That's of course if you know the type beforehand.

If you want to create the 'type' itself from a string you have, you will have to use reflection:

```
var viewType = Type.GetType("YourStoreApp.Views."+getMenu.pagePath.Substring(0, getMenu.pagePath.LastIndexOf("."));
```

Assuming the `pagePath` is not null.

The type string has to be fully qualified name, that is full assembly name and type (without extension), so e.g "YourStoreApp.Views.Services". The file name has to mirror the type name exactly for this to work though.

Now you can:

```
Frame.Navigate(viewType);
```

Comment: that's half the answer i was looking for. The bigger issue i'm having is the actual part that navigates to a layoutawarepage. As an example, navigating to the page specified in the pathPage parameter.

Comment: @Nathan I have edited the answer to provide further detail. Be careful when creating types from string though, it may be error-prone especially if your file names don't reflect type names. If they don't, you have to dig a bit deeper into reflection and discover the types yourself in your assembly, then match them by name and THEN create the concrete type.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass parameters to another page. I'm trying to use the parameters of the itemview to decide on which page to navigate too. So navigate to what ever is in the pathPage, in the example above Services.xaml. I think i'm getting confused. For the frame navigation, the typef(ItemDetailsView) bit. What is ItemDetailsView, is that a name or type of page?

Comment: @Nathan It was just an example, there's a follow up. :) Sorry for the confusion. The `ItemDetailsView` is a type, check the `Frame.Navigate` signature, it takes a `Type` and `object`. This means, you have to create the type from the string you have in the object clicked.

Comment: ah brill, that makes lots more sense. Just one last thing (sorry). In your example of "YourStoreApp.Views.Services" would the periods represent sub folders? thanks

Comment: @Nathan The string itself represents the full namespace where the type resides (fully qualified name, as I mentioned). Usually it's also the folder structure (so in this particular case 'YourStoreApp' is your base namespace, the 'Views' is a folder and namespace at the same time), but it's just a convention and it **doesn't have to be the same**. [Here's an article about fully qualified names.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: ah brilliant, that explains it. Thank you! On a side note, the entries will never change so there won't be a risk of having a null in pathPage.